# Incrementing quantity in shopping cart using React-Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am trying to increment/decrement quantity in my shopping cart, but I am getting errors. The "add to cart" and "remove from cart" actions are working fine.

```js
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const initialState = {
  items: {},
};

const cartSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'cart',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    addToCart: (state, action) => {
      const { id } = action.payload;
      if (state.items[id]) {
        state.items[id].quantity += 1;
      } else {
        state.items[id] = { ...action.payload, quantity: 1 };
      }
      console.log(state.items[id].quantity)
    },
    removeFromCart: (state, action) => {
      delete state.items[action.payload.id];
    },
    incrementQuantity: (state, action) => {
      const item = state.items.find((item) => item.id === action.payload);
      item.quantity++;
    },
    decrementQuantity: (state, action) => {
      const item = state.items.find((item) => item.id === action.payload);
      if (item.quantity === 1) {
        item.quantity = 1
      } else {
        item.quantity--;
      }
    },
  },
});

export const { addToCart, removeFromCart, incrementQuantity, decrementQuantity } = cartSlice.actions;
export const cartReducer = cartSlice.reducer;
```

I keep getting the error that `state.items.find` is not a function.

Comment: I think your `state.items` is not an `array`, but an `object` due to directly setting indexes, in `addToCart` and `removeFromCart`. Hence those doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The `items` state is an object, so there is no `find` property, e.g. `state.items.find` is undefined and not a function that can be called.

```js
const initialState = {
  items: {}, // <-- object, no find function property
};
```

Just access `items[id]` like was done in the `addToCart` and `removeFromCart` reducer cases.

```js
const cartSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'cart',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    addToCart: (state, action) => {
      const { id } = action.payload;

      if (state.items[id]) {
        state.items[id].quantity++;
      } else {
        state.items[id] = { ...action.payload, quantity: 1 };
      }
    },
    removeFromCart: (state, action) => {
      const { id } = action.payload;

      delete state.items[id];
    },
    incrementQuantity: (state, action) => {
      const id = action.payload;
      // or const { id } = action.payload; if like above

      if (state.items[id]) {
        state.items[id].quantity++;
      }
    },
    decrementQuantity: (state, action) => {
      const id = action.payload;
      // or const { id } = action.payload; if like above

      if (state.items[id]) {
        if (state.items[id].quantity === 1) {
          // Delete if quantity will go to 0
          delete state.items[id];
        } else {
          // Decrement otherwise
          state.items[id].quantity--;
        }
      }
    },
  },
});
```